# REST api service context and resources url

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, microservices

We have serveral services running on an application server and every service has a context. The name of the service is automatically added to the url, since there can be multiple services on the same application server.
Now we are creating a new service, which is called Draws, meaning the url will be

> http://url:port/Draws

However, now the discussion is the api paths (Resources) to this service. Since we are getting draws, in my mind this should be draws.
Which means it will have the url

> http://url:port/Draws/draws/{gameNo}

2x draws - **Thoughts?**

There are thoughts here that the service does only have draws and therefor Draws/{gameNo} is enough.
But in my mind, draws resource is the api interface of the service, like Draws is the book in a library, draws is the chapter... And it should be possible to add more chapters to the book.

Then to implementation, we are using Jersey. That would mean we would have a resource with @Path("{gameNo}").

**Edit 1:**
There are gateways in front of our services, so the context will never be exposed to end users, it's only there to point to an specific service. Since multiple services can run on the same host:port

**Edit 2:**
Context part of the url is part of the service discovery lookup

**Edit 3:**
We are actually not versioning in url, but in Accept header, so actually my url is the same as clementinos but the version part of the url

Comment: If the context will never be exposed, why are you concerned in having `draws` twice?

Comment: It's exposed internally, never to end users.

Comment: So, why don't you just change the context name to avoid having `draws` twice?

Comment: To what? I mean, the name of the service and project is Draws. The context is the name of the service - which is added by the application server. All services can't be on the same base url.

Comment: Which URL will your external users see?

Comment: The service is as I said, used internally by gatways, the gateways are the clients and they will indeed see the full url. They make a service lookup for Draws. and will be returned http://host:port/Draws. Then they use the resource of that service which is called draws.

Comment: And there could potentially also be another service which contains an resource called draws, but that is not the case. That would then be http://host_port/AnotherService/draws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid using 2x 'draws'.

Here is a possible way to design the URI structure.
Please note, that segments should be lower case (so don't use 'Draws')

```
<scheme>://<host>[:<port>]/<api-path>/<api-name>/<api-version>/<resource-path>
```

- **scheme** (eg. http)
- **host** is a fully qualified hostname, a DNS alias hiding the equipment and physical location of the API implementation. It contains information about the environment when it is a non-productive environment (test, int).
- **port** should be the default http port (80) and thus can be omitted. Other ports can be used for non-productive environments.
- **api** **path** separates the REST API from other resources served by the server (e.g. a webapp). It is usually of the form /api. For servers serving only REST apis, it can be omitted.
- **api name** gathers a set of resources in a kind of package. This is the unit of publishing and versioning.
- **api version** is the version of the API. It has the form v[major-version-number]
- **resource** **path** is composed of the resource URI segments

Comment: The only difference to mine is that you actually added api-version. I ignored the api-path since it does not really matter in my case.

Comment: Regarding the api-version, we've had a lot of discussion regarding if it should be in the Accept header or url, not yet decided. Not sure how well swagger handles versioning in headers.

Comment: And well, the Api-name, would in my case be Draws, which is the name of the service, and the resource name is also draws.

Comment: This is nice @clementino, can you supply resources?

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess your mind with books or library or chapters. Only look your entities: Is "Draws" your entity? Then it should be as `http://url:port/draws/{gameNo}`

For Rest API designing, you can read following resources:

- [Rest In Practice](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805838.do)
- [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html)

I suggest you to have a look on Richardson Maturity Model.

Also I like [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3). (Old days they used to suggest us to read code to improve our talents, now you can read rest APIs also.)

Comment: Draws is the url-context of the service in the application server. Then Draws is for the resource draws the entity. But there are minds here that thinks that the only thing the service will return is draws, and since the context is already Draws, the api of the service does not need to start with "draws", but for me, thats the resource of the service. The context(Name of the service) does not matter at all

Comment: You don't need to put a name to the servlet context. Leave it as "/".

Comment: So how would you solve that 2 different services would have draws as a resource, being on the same host and port?

Comment: That was just an option. But ... do you have 2 different services with the same "draws" entity? Or with different "draws" entities? If there were 2 different "draws" entities, then your entities should be different than "draws", maybe "Xdraws"

Comment: It was an example, the entity name does not need to be the same as the resource name in my mind, even if that would look better.

Answer (score 0):

If you design a Draws service, you url should be:

> http://url:port/draws/{gameNo}

If you plan to extend the service with other endpoints, probably you are designing something more generic. If this is the case, name it accordingly.

In any way you shouldn't go with draws/draws.

Also, I would recommend to use lower case and https (if you can).

Recently I posted a summary of the most often questions that arise when designing RESTful API - [How To Design Practical RESTful API](https://codewithyury.com/how-to-design-practical-restful-api/) , which could be helpful.

Comment: The Draws is the name of the service, an context of the service. Which is automatically added in the application server. and "draws" is actually an endpoint in that same service